# Array de la tabla de las potencias de 2.(PHP; JS)

Tags: php, javascript, array

es la primera vez que estoy haciendo arrays y la verdad ando un poco perdida.
Como dice el título, estoy intentando almacenar en un array la tabla de las potencias de 2 y mostrar el contenido del array. (en PHP y JS para un ejercicio de clase)
Pues bien, no entiendo **NADA**.
He hecho esto:

```
<?php
  $tabla=[ ];
        for($i=0; $i<=20; $i++) {
            $tabla[ ]= 2**$i;
        }
            echo "Potencias del 2: ";
            echo "<br>";
            print_r($tabla);
       ?>
```

- Pregunta 1: ¿Está bien así?
- Pregunta 2: Pensé que poniendo un br ahí
  me haría un salto de línea o algo, pero me sale todo seguido.
- Pregunta 3: Es normal que salga "Array blablabla"??
- Pregunta 4: Para    hacerlo en JS, sé que tengo que hacer un div y
  asignarle un id. Y    después hacer el document.getElementById y eso,
  pero nanai!!!! Me    resulta imposible hacer nada :(

Comment: Son muchas cosas al mismo tiempo, es importante tener claro dos conceptos de entrada: cliente y servidor. Javascript trabaja del lado del cliente y PHP del lado del servidor. Si necesitas pasar la tabla al cliente puedes hacerlo directamente desde PHP, creando una salida HTML que mostrarías en el cliente, por lo que realmente no necesitarías Javascript para esto, a no ser que sea un ejercicio en el que te exigen Javascript (entonces debes indicarlo en la pregunta). Por otro lado `print_r` suele usarse para verificar contenidos (aunque `var_dump` es mejor para eso) ... sigue ...

Comment: ... Si lo que quieres es una salida elegante, puedes construir código HTML dentro del bucle `for` por ejemplo y luego hacer un `echo`  de ese contenido. Si el `echo` ocurre dentro de un contexto HTML se verá bien, y se verá también el salto `<br>`, pero en un contexto de prueba, como la consola, no se verá, porque no estás en un contexto HTML. Volvemos al principio: distinguir entre lo que es el cliente (Javascript, HTML)  y lo que es el servidor (PHP). Son dos mundos distintos y complementarios. Como dije antes, desde el servidor puedes producir salidas para el cliente. ...

Comment: ... ¿Y Javascript? Pues Javascript trabaja del lado del cliente, y sirve para interactuar, por ejemplo, escuchar eventos que ocurren en el cliente, pasar datos entre cliente/servidor y actualizar la página sin recargar. Para este caso concreto, no tienes por qué complicarte con Javascript, a no ser que te lo hayan exigiddo, para fines de aprendizaje. En ese caso, debes redactar mejor la pregunta, explicando exactamente qué es lo que quieres y qué problemas tienes. Sin hacer preguntas existenciales, que el sitio no es para eso, sino para problemas concretos de código.

Comment: Tus dudas parecen estar enfocadas a como trabajar con arrelgos, por lo que te recomiendo leer [este articulo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php) de la documentación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vas bien, sólo pon atención en dónde estas realizando el **"echo "Potencias del 2: ";**
esta fuera del **for** y además no estas incluyendo **$i** en ese mismo **echo**.

Para la duda del **br** misma situación, esta fuera del **for**.

En cuanto a la tabla que deseas mostrar hace falta que recorras **$tabla** y no sólo el **print_r()**

En cuanto a la última duda de JS, ya tienes retro por parte de la comunidad referente a desarrollo del lado del cliente y servidor.

Te comparto un ejemplo funcional de tu código, aplicando las observaciones que te menciono.

```
<?php
    
    $tabla=[];
    
    for($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
        $potencia = 2**$i; 
        $tabla[ ]= $potencia;
        echo "Potencias del 2<sup>". $i ."</sup>: " . $potencia;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($tabla);
    echo "<br><hr>";
?>

    <table border="1" width="20%">
        <caption>Potencias del 2</caption>
<?php
    foreach ($tabla as &$valor) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $valor . "</td></tr>";
    }
?>
    </table>
```